# get sum qty from dynamic multiple table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table master like this :

```
item
+-------+---------+
|item_id|item_name|
+-------+---------+
|  001  |  Car A  |
|  002  |  Car B  |
+-------+---------+

process
+-------+---------+----------+
|proc_id|proc_name|proc_table|
+-------+---------+----------+
|   1   |    HD   |   tb_HD  |
|   2   |    RL   |   tb_RL  |
|   3   |    FU   |   tb_FU  |
|   4   |    TR   |   tb_TR  |
+-------+---------+----------+

item_process
+------------+-------+
|proc_item_id|proc_id|
+------------+-------+
|    001     |   1   |
|    001     |   2   |
|    001     |   4   |
|    002     |   2   |
|    002     |   3   |
|    002     |   4   |
+------------+-------+

tb_HD
+----+---+
|item|qty|
+----+---+
|001 |100|
+----+---+

tb_RL
+----+---+
|item|qty|
+----+---+
|001 |50 |
|002 |70 |
+----+---+

tb_FU
+----+---+
|item|qty|
+----+---+
|002 | 20|
|002 |150|
+----+---+

tb_TR
+----+---+
|item|qty|
+----+---+
|002 |30 |
+----+---+
```

I want result like this when I select item_id 002

```
+-------+---------+-------+
|item_id|proc_name|sum_qty|
+-------+---------+-------+
|  002  |    RL   |   70  |
|  002  |    FU   |  170  |
|  002  |    TR   |   30  |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

My problem is how I get sum qty from multiple tables when the condition is a dynamic table name (get from table process). can table name get from select other tables in one query for sum qty field? 
this example query :

```
SELECT a.item_id, 
   b.proc_name, 
   b.proc_table, 
   (SELECT SUM(c.qty) FROM b.proc_table c GROUP BY c.item ) AS qty 
FROM item_process a
LEFT JOIN process b ON a.proc_id=b.proc_id;
```

SQLFIDDLE [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2ead7/11)

Comment: This looks like homework.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: SELECT a.item_id, 
       b.proc_name, 
       b.proc_table, 
       (SELECT SUM(c.qty) FROM b.proc_table c GROUP BY c.item ) AS qty 
FROM item_process a
LEFT JOIN process b ON a.proc_id=b.proc_id;

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to store the quantities in 3 separate tables.

Comment: the quantities are split into several table process for fast response when searching data because this table will store million data. if I store 1 table, I worry about crash data..all data will be gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was found the solution..
i create view tb_hd, tb_rl, tb_fu ,tb_tr union all in 1 view